# Visual Basic specific characteristics

Tags: vb.net

I'm looking for in depth information about Visual Basic. For example, Scoping and binding behaviors, subprogram and package facilities, etc.

Are there any resources, preferably accessible online, that you know of?

Edit:
I'm looking for information such as: VB uses lexical or dynamic scoping; binding for X happens at compile time/load time/runtime and is static or dynamic. Basically a more in depth look at the characteristics of the language.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are pretty much the same as C#.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308470
http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html

If this is not what you are looking for please add more details on what you are looking for and why.

.NET is lexical scope, a variable name is only accessible within the scope it is defined.
Most items are bound at compile time unless they are lazy loading (load when needed) or dynamic (compiled at run time).

You can check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic

It sound like you would benefit most from a intro/tutorial more then a facts sheet as an intro will explain each concept as it comes up.  If you already know a programming language you might also look for an intro to VB specific to that language (like [VB.Net for Java programmer](http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/ahmed.rajek/Arrays12112006232141PM/Arrays.aspx)).  See also http://www.csharphelp.com/2005/11/net-framework-for-java-programmers/

Comment: Thank you. I read the white paper, it was helpful and clarified a few points for me.

Comment: Oh sorry, it's my first post. Sure I'll accept it as correct. Just as an afterthought, if there's anything more general (less comparison oriented, see my edit in the original post) you have, I'd gladly accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

When you need a complete description for a language, always consult the manufacturer specification. In case of VB.NET, you can get the language specification [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15751) (VB.NET 2003)

> The Visual Basic .NET Language Specification provides a complete
>   description of the Visual Basic .NET language.